# Pls help newbie

Tags: python

Задача:

1. Создать функцию update_car_info,
   в которой все именованные аргументы будут объединены в
   словарь car.
2. Добавить в словарь новый ключ is_available с значением True
3. Вернуть из функции измененный словарь.
4. Вызвать функцию с именованными аргументами brand и price,
   их значения могут быть любыми
5. Вывести в терминал результат вызова функции

```py
def update_car_info(**car):
    newdict = {'is_available': True}
    return newdict


update_car_info('brand', 'price')
```

> TypeError: update_car_info() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его суть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
def update_car_info(**car):
  car['is_available'] = True
  return car


print(update_car_info(brand='BMW', price=100500))
```

Comment: почему минусуете этот ответ?